# "Generic" function in C - use same time-measuring function for 2 different libraries

Tags: c

I found here, on SO, a simple function to measure the execution time of a function in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>

int64_t timespecDiff(struct timespec *timeA_p, struct timespec *timeB_p)
{
  return ((timeA_p->tv_sec * 1000000000) + timeA_p->tv_nsec) -
           ((timeB_p->tv_sec * 1000000000) + timeB_p->tv_nsec);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  struct timespec start, end;
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);

  // Some code I am interested in measuring 

  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);

  uint64_t timeElapsed = timespecDiff(&end, &start);
}
```

Now I would like to use it to measure some cryptographic function executions. For now on, Im interesting only in `Openssl` and `Crypto++` (but would like to extend the list with other libraries).

In C++ I would use templates for this, but how about C? Let's say, I have 2 functions:

`void md4_openssl(...);` and `void md4_cryptopp(...);` where all the parameters setups (keys, buffers, ...) are INSIDE those functions. Now, how can I make my measruring function more "generic"? In the way that something like this would be possible:

```
void measureTime()
{
   function(); // could be md4_openssl or md4_cryptopp
}
```

Of course, I would use `opnessl` if installed, but if it is not, it will call `cryptopp` function

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking. Though to help answer your question, is your openssl/cryptopp dependency known at build time or runtime?

Comment: Depends on your precise needs, but I usually print `time@beginning - time@end` in order to measure.

Comment: One word: "plastics".  Oops, I mean 2 words: "function pointers".

Answer (score 3):

The obvious way is a pass a pointer to function to `measureTime()`:

```
uint64_t measureTime(void (*fp)(void)) {
    struct timespec start, end;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);

    fp();       //  Call the function you want to measure

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);

    return timespecDiff(&end, &start);
}

void measure_ssl(void) {
    md4_openssl(1, 2, 3, whatever);    // Setup and call however you need to
}

void measure_crypt(void) {
    md4_cryptopp(1, 2, 3, whatever);    // Setup and call however you need to
}

int main(void) {
    uint64_t t1 = measureTime(measure_ssl);
    uint64_t t2 = measureTime(measure_crypt);

    //  Do something with t1 and t2

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: In response to your comment, any function pointer you pass to a function must have the signature matching the parameter. If you need to call functions which have different signatures, then you need to wrap them as the above code does.

If your wrapper function can take care of the parameters, then you can just use the above code without modification. In other words, `measure_ssl()` can call `md4_openssl(1, 2, 3, "more", "args")` and `measure_crypt()` can call `md4_cryptopp(5.4, "different", ARGS)` or whatever.

If you do need to actually provide the arguments to `measureTime()`, you'll have to pass information to your wrapper functions and have them do some interpretation. If each function took, say, one pointer, but of a different type, you could just pass a single `void *` and pass it on.

If the arguments can be completely different and unpredictable, then the simplest way to do it is create a `struct` and pass the address of that, for instance:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <time.h>

void func1(int a, int b, int c) {
    printf("Let's count to %d, %d and %d!\n", a, b, c);
}

struct func1_params {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

void func2(double d, const char * c) {
    printf("There are %f %ss\n", d, c);
}

struct func2_params {
    double d;
    const char * c;
};

void func1_wrap(void * params) {
    struct func1_params * p = params;
    func1(p->a, p->b, p->c);
}

void func2_wrap(void * params) {
    struct func2_params * p = params;
    func2(p->d, p->c);
}

int64_t timespecDiff(struct timespec *timeA_p, struct timespec *timeB_p) {
  return ((timeA_p->tv_sec * 1000000000) + timeA_p->tv_nsec) -
           ((timeB_p->tv_sec * 1000000000) + timeB_p->tv_nsec);
}

uint64_t measureTime(void (*fp)(void *), void * params) {
    struct timespec start, end;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);

    fp(params);

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);

    return timespecDiff(&end, &start);
}

int main(void) {
    struct func1_params p1 = {1, 2, 3};
    uint64_t t1 = measureTime(func1_wrap, &p1);

    struct func2_params p2 = {3.14159, "pie"};
    uint64_t t2 = measureTime(func2_wrap, &p2);

    printf("First func took time %" PRIu64 " units.\n", t1);
    printf("Second func took time %" PRIu64 " units.\n", t2);

    return 0;
}
```

This is generic, in that `measureTime()` doesn't need to know anything about the functions you're calling, or anything about the `struct`. You could compile that into a library, and then much later write, say, `func1_wrap()` and `struct func1_params` and pass them in. You can measure the time of any function you like just by writing a `struct` to contain the arguments and a wrapper function of type `void (*)(void *)` to accept a pointer to that struct and pass the members as arguments to the function you're interested in.

In the above code, I've provided the definitions of `func1()` and `func2()` to provide a complete working example, but you can think of these as your `md4_openssl()` and `md4_cryptopp()` functions instead, and have your wrapper functions call those.

Comment: I thought using a macro but this solution is actually much better. Is there some trick such that you could use it directly on the functions with the arguments? I mean `uint64_t t1 = measureTime(md4_openssl(1, 2, 3, whatever));`

Comment: @Emilien: If all the functions you want to call have the same signature, then yes, you can get rid of the wrappers, and just declare `measureTime()` as `uint64_t measureTime(void (*fp)(int, int, int, const char *))` or with whatever types they take. If they don't take the same parameters, you'd need to work around it, e.g. create a different `struct` for each function that you could store the parameters in, and pass that to `measureTime()` as a `void *`, and have your wrapper functions deference and interpret it.

Comment: Yeah, I would need the version WITHOUT wrappers. Is it possible? I mean, md4 from cryptopp takes different parametrs than md from openssl

Comment: Yeah, it's possible, I'll update the answer in a little while.

Comment: @mirx: Updated with a more general example where the functions you're interested in take different parameters.